# netcat(nc) complain about invalid port

Tags: shell, netcat

I have my nc command in a text file, a.txt, as following:

```
/bin/nc -w 3 -zv 123.123.123.123 1195
```

If I ran: `bash a.txt`, there's error: `nc: port number invalid: 1195`.
But if I copy the nc command, run it with bash prompt. The command is working, no error.
Any idea? Thanks.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Probably your file has DOS newlines (`\r\n`) as opposed to UNIX newlines (`\n`), so the port number being passed to `nc` is actually `$'1195\r'`.

Comment: BTW, the bash tag on StackOverflow tells you to check for that before you ask questions; see item #1 in "before asking about problematic code" in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info

Comment: If you run `bash -x a.txt`, btw, it'll show you the commands it's actually running, which would remove all doubt here.

Comment: It's really the problem of the DOS newlines, stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info is useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Probably your file has DOS newlines (`\r\n`) as opposed to UNIX newlines (`\n`), so the port number being passed to `nc` is actually `$'1195\r'`. – Charles Duffy